# Git cannot detect the file which has been modified

Tags: git

> Git version : 1.9.1 , IDE : webstorm 8

For example , I modified `A.file`,`B.file`,`C.file`, then I used command `git status` . I  could not find the status of `A.file`, it seemed to nothing change with `A.file`. I could not `git commit` `A.file` of course.
But `B.file` and `C.file` were just normal.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure your `A.file` is in the same directory like your git repository you are working on?

Comment: Please post some commands and output.

Comment: pretty sure. @ckruczek

Comment: Then we need more information on your commands and you might check the first provided answer.

Comment: @Spy Is the file even being tracked by Git? What does `git ls-files A.file` tell you? Does that command produce any output or not? If not, it means you have yet to stage `A.file`; run `git add A.file`.

Comment: Maybe first provided answer is right . It reminds me to check `A.file`. `A.file` is indeed in a folder which is in the `.gitignore` . @ckruczek

Comment: @Jubobs thx , problem solved. Its an issue about `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `A.file` is not mentioned in a `.gitignore` file in the current or parent directories, or in `.git/info/exclude` within your local repository.  See [gitignore doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for details.

Comment: Btw , whers is `.git/info/exclude` ?

Comment: In your repository directory you should find a `.git` directory - the `exclude` file is in there within an `info` sub-directory.  New repositories for current versions of Git all have this file as standard, but it only contains sample/commented lines.